# View/edit rows in SharePoint List that only relevant to the specific team

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, modern-experience, microsoft-lists

I'm trying to create a SharePoint List in my organization. The list is created centrally, which allows different teams to view and edit the rows that only relevant to them.

There is a column which indicates which row belongs to which team. How can I do this in SharePoint?

Below image shows what I mean.

[image]

Comment: You need item-level permissions. You can do that manually or with backend code like an event receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps for your requirements:

1. Create a SharePoint group for each team (if not created already)
2. Create a power automate flow which will run on item creation or update (as per your requirements)
3. Break permissions inheritance on newly created item using power automate flow
4. Grant permissions to respective SharePoint group based on selection of "Team".
5. For safer side grant permissions to site admin as well on each list item.

Follow below article for breaking and granting permissions: [Power Automate - Break Inheritance And Set List Item-Level Permissions In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/power-automate-break-inheritance-and-set-list-item-level-permissions-in-sharep/)

Comment: Hi @civilized_caveman_sg, did you try this solution? let me know if you still need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

1.Set permissions on a single row.

Just as we can set individual permissions for files in a document library, we can also set individual permissions for each row in a SharePoint list. Of course, by default, all rows in a SharePoint list inherit permissions from the site. Just like with files and folders, you can break inheritance, but you need to do it manually (try it if you don't have much data).

[image: Manage access]
[image: Stop sharing]

2.Add and set folder permissions.

Setting list can create folders:list settings->Advanced settings->Folders->Yes->ok

[image: create floders]

Put items in the corresponding folder and set the permissions of the folder respectively.
[image: floder permission]