# List permissions in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, groups

I have a list in SharePoint online. The users have a hierarchy that goes like this:

Department Owner Group is the owner of this group. I have three other groups - Team 1, Team 2 and Team 3.

Each of the Teams have Users in it. All the Teams have "Contribute" permissions. For example, Team 1 has User 1 and User 2. Now, a User 1 from Team 1 inputs an "Item" into the list. I don't want any of the members from Team 2 and Team 3 view that "Item".

To do that, I set Item Level permissions as "Read Items that were created by the User" and "Create items and edit items that were created by the user". This ensures that users from Team 2 and Team 3 Groups have no visibility of that "Item".

However, I want User 2 from Team 1 to view and edit items that belong to Team 1. How do I do this?

Comment: You cannot do it using SharePoint out of the box Advanced settings > Item level permissions. You will have to break permission inheritance at item level and grant the permissions to your "team" groups.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this cannot be done out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get this without setting unique permissions on each item (which will be a nightmare to maintain). Perhaps you could build a flow of some sort.

The easiest way in my opinion would be:

- Create different list for each team with custom permissions to each specific team
- Create folders in the list you already for each team, and set custom permissions for each team to have their own folder where they create the list items in, this way you'll only handle the permissions on the folders and the items within will be accessible/editable by everyone who have permission to access the folder.

Comment: Thanks for this. Let's say I create three different lists for Team 1, Team 2 and Team 3. I want all the list items into a Master List so that I can carry out analytics on the data from the three teams. Is that possible? And whenever a value is updated in the team list for a particular item, the value should be updated to the Master List.

Comment: I suggest not creating that kind of relationship, even thought it's possible using PowerApps/Flow. Depending on your tool for analytics, you should be able to use the 3 list as different data sources and aggregate the data as long as the 3 lists are identical.

Comment: Thanks very much Chris. I will take your advice. I am planning on using Power BI for analytics.

Comment: Best of luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it using SharePoint out of the box "Advanced settings > Item level permissions".

You will have to break permissions inheritance at individual item level and grant the permissions to your "team" groups.

If you are storing the team name or some related information against each list item to identify item belongs to each team, you can manage permissions using the Power automate flow or you will have to manually manage the permissions.

Follow below steps for automating permissions management:

1. Create a SharePoint group for each team (if not created already).
2. Create a power automate flow which will run on item creation or update (as per your requirements).
3. Break permissions inheritance on newly created item using power automate flow.
4. Grant permissions to respective SharePoint group based on selection of "Team".
5. For safer side grant full control permissions to site admin as well on each list item.

Follow below article for breaking and granting permissions: [Power Automate - Break Inheritance And Set List Item-Level Permissions In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/power-automate-break-inheritance-and-set-list-item-level-permissions-in-sharep/)

**Related read**:

1. [View/edit rows in SharePoint List that only relevant to the specific team](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304080/view-edit-rows-in-sharepoint-list-that-only-relevant-to-the-specific-team/304084#304084)
2. [Restrict user access](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304393/restrict-user-access/304413#304413)
3. [Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
4. [SharePoint limits - Items in lists and libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#items-in-lists-and-libraries?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)